# Limit behavior of MSTs edge sets under addition of weight doubling vertex potentials

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $G(V,E)$ be a complete [simple graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html) for which each of its edges has an associated weight.

The edge-set of every spanning tree of $G$ is trivially adjacent the $n$ vertices of $G$ and has $n-1$ elements, which gives us $n-1$ conditions for $n$ vertex-potentials $\pi_1,\,\dotsc,\,\pi_n$  such that $\omega_{ij} =\pi_i+\pi_j$ when $\omega_{ij}$ is the weight of an edge $e_{ij}$ in the spanning tree.
Adding the constraint that $\sum_i\pi_i =0$ uniquely defines the $\pi_i$.

> **Question:**
>
> if we repeatedly
>
> - determine the edge-set of $G$'s **M**inimum-weight **S**panning **T**ree
> - calculate the vertex potentials $\pi_i$ such that $\sum_i\pi_i=0$, $\pi_i+\pi_j=\omega_{ij}$ for the weight of MST-edges
> - add for *every* edge $e_{ij}\in E$  to its associated weight $\pi_i+\pi_j$
>
> will the set of MST-edges "converge", i.e. be invariant after a finite number of iterations or are limit-cycles also possible?

Comment: Is the MST unique?  If not, at the first step, do you just pick one such?

Comment: @LSpice to make things simpler lets assume that MSTs are unique, i.e. that a suffiently small random "error" had been added to the edge-weights before starting the algorithm.